# StringRequest vs HttpURLConnection in AsyncTask: Which is better way to get data from external MySQL server in Android App

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

In SO and elsewhere on the internet, I have found two ways to get data from an external MySQL server to Android app.

First, we output the required data from MySQL server to a webpage using PHP. Then we get the outputted data from the webpage using one of the following two methods:

1. Using StringRequest class from the Volley library
2. Using HttpURLConnection class in an AsyncTask

My question is which of the above two is a better way to do this? Or is there a third way which is better than both of the above?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Volley is better!

Comment: @Mithun ji: I see, thanks! Could you add your comment as an answer so that I could accept it?